# How to add a button control dynamically into a GridView cell ? VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, gridview, addition

Look, it´s simple. I have a GridView which is populated with data from my database.

What I want is put a button in each cell that contains a specific datum.

Pls, look the image below. It describes exactly what I want

In VB.NET, pls! =)

[Example Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/821/m5i.png/)

Thanks very much!

Comment: Post your `GridView` markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to define the button control inside of the `<Columns>` section of your `GridView` markup, like this:

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" runat="server">
    <columns>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="DateColumn" headertext="Date"/>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Positive
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label id="LabelPositive" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PositiveColumn")%>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button id="ButtonPositive" runat="server" Text="Show" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Negative
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label id="LabelNegative" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NegativeColumn")%>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button id="ButtonNegative" runat="server" Text="Show" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Neutral
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label id="LabelNeutral" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NeutralColumn")%>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Button id="ButtonNeutral" runat="server" Text="Show" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="NoCommentsColumn" headertext="No Comments"/>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="TotalColumn" headertext="Total"/>
    </columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Note: The `datafield` and `Eval()` calls are bound to made up names like `NeutralColumn` and `NoCommentsColumn`, substitute those names with your real database field names.

Comment: Thanks very much Karl. It´s exactly what I was looking for! =D

Comment: Great, glad it helped. If you feel this answer helped you, then feel free to up-vote it and/or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add while data binding the grid. Look for an event call and handle your code there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx